# Is there a way to combine sheets with the same beginning 2 alphabets into one sheet?

Tags: vba

I wanted to consolidates data of the same headers and no. of columns into the same one sheet. I have sheets of different countries e.g. US, UK, EU1, EU2, EU3, EU4.... and I am wondering if it is possible to combine sheet with name EU1, EU2, EU3, and EU4 into one sheet with vba coding?

PS. the number of EU changes each time there maybe 5 EU in other file or even 6 EU sheets so I would like it to be generalized to other file as well

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are all your sheets in a single file? Are you asking how to collate all rows from all sheets into a single sheet, or how to break one sheet into several sheets based on the entry in a particular column? How is your data laid out. Which columns hold the data, over what range?

Comment: all sheets are in single file and all of them have same structure, covered the same number of columns but different number of rows. I would like to put e.g. data in EU2 under sheet EU1 making them continuous

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Aggregate
Dim ws as worksheet
Dim Target as worksheet
dim x as integer
dim t as range
Set target = worksheets(1)
set t = target.range(target.usedrange.rows.count,1) 'first blank cell
for x = 2 to worksheets.count
    set ws = worksheets(x)
    ws.usedrange.copy t
    set t = target.range(target.usedrange.rows.count,1) 'first blank cell
next ws
End sub
```